# why service references being showed as folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I am doing a wpf application using visual studio and team server foundation. I have added three service references and was working perfectly till last day. When i opened the project today two of the service references are turned to folders, so am not able to update the references or configure them. what could be the problem?

Note: The project was initially mapped to difference folder(say C:/sample/) , i removed the mapping from the existing folder and mapped to another folder(say D:/sample/), i have not removed any files.

[image]

Comment: Can you do a diff on the csproj in your source control?

Comment: @Ian Yes, i did, but it does not show any changes

Comment: were any changes made to your VS2010 install (updates??) or any updates made to TFS?

Comment: @DavidHoerster i removed the mapping and mapped to a different folder? could that be a problem?

Comment: You need to verify in *.csproj what are the differences between the way `svcImageProcess` is declared against the others. Open it in a text/xml editor.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I don't understand what you mean by removing the mapping and mapped it to a different folder.  Can you provide information in your question about what changes you made to your project?  Provide what files you removed/moved...and also provide information about what you're trying to do by altering Visual Studio generated mapping files.  Thanks!

Comment: @DavidHoerster I modified the question! i have come across this problem many times by removing the references and adding it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project has a higher *.NET Framework* version than your *Visual Studio* version can support.